Can doctors administer an experimental treatment without patient consent in an emergency?
Is it legal for doctors to administer an experimental treatment or drug to a patient in an emergency situation where the patient is unable to provide consent?
To provide an example scenario: An unconscious patient is brought into emergency and will die without immediate treatment. For some reason - an allergy, a pre-existing condition, the hospital being short on supplies - conventional drugs or treatments aren't an option but experimental ones are. The patient, however, is unconscious so they can't provide consent for the treatment and have nobody that can consent for them. Doctors have an obligation to help but also to not harm, so what happens in a situation like this?

It may be worth clarifying exactly what you mean by "experimental treatments".  One interpretation would be "Part of a clinical trial ongoing in that dept.", another would be "an off label drug use or procedure variation that has been positively discussed in the literature that the clinician thought would be appropriate in this situation".

or it could be "A spark of genius/madness to try this totally novel procedure that is unprecedented by any medical field and which breaks all ethical limits" (e.g. transplanting a cow's heart to keep the patient alive)

@Trish I wouldn't call that "experimental" within the meaning of the relevant laws. More like "ad-hoc" and "last ditch attempt". As such it's really a different question about scope of medical judgement.

Legal or not -- the important thing is that Dr. House has saved another patient!

@PaulJohnson Welcome to the Island of Dr. Moreau and Frankenstein Castle :P

Could "off-label" use of a drug fall under the concept of experimental? The doctor might have several drugs available that are not "supposed" to be used in the situation, but might actually be the saving solution.

@ghellquist AIUI this hinges on the word "experimental". In order to fall under that term legally, the procedure has to be part of an actual experiment: a controlled medical trial done with the intent of finding out whether the experimental treatment is safe and effective. That doesn't cover one-off ad-hoc interventions because they don't tell you anything beyond "that patient survived".

united-states
Yes. This is specifically covered by 21 CFR 50.24. It is not ad-hoc but the study has to be approved by an IRB, it has to be a life-threatening situation, consent cannot be reasonably obtained before intervention, appropriate animal studies and similar have been carried out so that it is believed the treatment is beneficial, etc.
A key element is public disclosure. For example, notices for a study conducted for cardiac arrest treatment at a certain hospital's emergency room could be published in newspapers. There could be an opt-out mechanism, for example, by the patient carrying a form on them.
Similar mechanisms exist in other countries.

This only applies if the patient is part of the study. Not everything a doctor does, including using  drugs for off-label use, is research.

@Scott Seidman I think it is necessary to distinguish experimental from research. Some treatments are described as experimental by insurors who deny payment for it. While user 71659's answer is clear and concise about the procedures for approved research, I think the question is ambiguous.

The question has it's ambiguities, @DavidSmith, but Title 21 is about the FDA, which does not regulate the practice of medicine at all.

@Scott Seidman Yes. I was long time member of an IRB and have voted to approve such research. A doctor treating an unconscious or incoheret patient has considerable professional leeway to try uncommon methods, often called experimental.

It's also worth noting that in certain circumstances, like sometimes when a patient has been in cardiac arrest for a period of time and is unresponsive to other remedies, a medical team may try anything that they think has any chance of getting a response that would get their heart beating again. It's the concept of, "you can't die if you're already dead." If there's a experimental treatment handy, it may be administered. I don't know what the legal framework of this is, but it is somewhat common.

germany
In Germany everybody — even third parties entirely unrelated to the events or their protagonists — is obliged to help people in danger or in an emergency per §323c StGB, as long as it is not an unreasonable burden, in particular does not substantially endanger the helper, and as long as it does not conflict with other important duties. (This idea is quite foreign to common law systems where such an obligation mostly arises for people with some circumstantial or personal relation to the events.)
In Germany, this principle applies to the the doctor-patient relationship: A doctor generally has an obligation to treat any and all patients in emergencies.
I must assume that the concrete application depends on the concrete case, especially the cost/benefit calculation a qualified observer would make regarding the experimental treatment, especially compared to possible more conservative treatments. But, if we want to construct an extreme situation:

Death is imminent and virtually ensured without treatment
No established treatment is available
But an experimental treatment is available
While that treatment is still officially experimental and could normally not legally be administered outside clinical trials, it has shown great promise and on the verge of being approved.

In such a situation I would even construct an obligation to treat for a doctor. It's as if you have a rope you could throw to a drowning swimmer but you refuse to because it's just a clothesline and might break, so you stand back and do nothing instead. That seems utterly wrong.

Please note that on-duty medical personnel, including doctors and paramedics, is almost certain to have a Garantenstellung, so that they are obliged to act under § 13 StGB, possibly incurring much more severe penalties than under § 323c StGB. Take this example, the headline says "unterlassene Hilfeleistung" but the text says "Der Vorwurf: fahrlässige Körperverletzung durch Unterlassung" – a very different thing.

@SebastianKoppehel Interesting. Perhaps. One issue: The law requires that the missing action (here: experimental treatment) would "almost assuredly" have prevented the damage (here: patient's death); in other words, is the causal link there which makes doing nothing equally criminal as an actual act. Depending on the concrete circumstance that sure causality would probably often be doubtful. I mean, the doctor didn't let the patient bleed or starve to death. (Here is a University of Potsdam text.)

@SebastianKoppehel I think doctors often enjoy a wide liberty in choosing their treatment. Kunstfehler are a notoriously difficult thing to prove. The leeway they may have in being progressive and try the experimental stuff may extend in the opposite, conservative direction. You can hardly blame someone for primum non nocere. ;-)

You are right, the standard are different for § 323c (mere "possibility of success" is enough to trigger an obligation to act). It would, therefore, depend on how, for example, an expert witness would assess the experimental treatment's chances of success.

By the way, you may find this verdict interesting (civil suit, patient suing for damage). The court saw grave malpractice in a case where Aciclovir was not used to treat herpes encephalitis at a time when it was not yet officially approved to treat that condition (but off-label use was already widely practiced).

@SebastianKoppehel that verdict is (from my reading) EXACTLY what OP is asking for. Btw for details: the suit isn't even about not giving Aciclovir, it's about that medication being given only after the herpes encephalitis diagnosis was strongly confirmed (with some delay) instead of - as the patient demands retroactively - on reasonable suspicion. So the "experimental" (off-label) drug was given, just not experimentally enough (before certain diagnosis that would certainly warrant the off-label use)

@SebastianKoppehel Perhaps you'd like to write an answer including that trial?
